# Changes made in an zend application are not reflected immediately

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am a newbie with zend-framework and I am building a small application.. Everything was working fine till yesterday... Suddenly today I found that the changes made were not reflecting at all.. so I restarted the machine and found that the changes done were now reflecting ... But again the same thing ... Is there some kind of cache that i need to clear ? Any help, any directions are appreciated ... surely i can't restart the machine after every change...

Sample code: 
Controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{    
     $this->info="Please login here";
     //$this->view->form = new Application_Form_LoginForm();
     //$this->getForm();
     $this->view->form = $this->getForm();
}
```

View:

```
<?php 
  echo $this->info;
```

In order to test this, I am just changing the value of $this->info

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: Zend wont use any cache out of the box that you dont tell it too. Do you use APC cache or HTTP cache-control headers?

Comment: nopes, I am not using apc cache or http cache-control ... I am mostly dealing with forms and stuff..

Comment: It should be `$this->view->info="Please login here";` inside the controller.

Comment: @Salman: even that does not work .. and more importantly the form which I am creating in index is also not appearing on view page because i commented it before restarting..

Comment: In that case check your zend installation, folder structure etc. Maybe you are looking at the wrong controller/view file.

Comment: Thanks to all of you Alex, Patrick and Salman.. I finally cracked it .. was a browser caching issue..I have updated the answer in the edit of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this one out. This looked like a browser caching issue; the browser was caching the page and hence any changes were not visible.

After Patrick confirmed that there is no in-built default caching, I started looking for external factors. First stopped my apache and found that browser was still showing the page. Finally, I tried on Google Chrome and it was working as normal. So, I cleared my browser cache and it was working as normal.

Thanks to all of you and StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your machine will most likely be using APC which has `APC stat` set to 1.

Setting it to 0 should fix this.

Zend Framework which is just a PHP library does not have any caching built in to your views, and this sources like a memory caching problem.